# React doesn't rerender page before fetching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a code like following.

React hook:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(() => true);  // expect to rerender page to show loading now.
    const selectedItem = itemLists[id];
    const promise = getData(selectedItem);

    promise
      .then((res) => {
        setIsLoading(() => false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [itemLists, id]);
```

and HTML:

```
return (
        <>
          {isLoading ? (
            <Loading />
          ) : (
            <h1> page content here <h1/>
          )
        <>
)
```

What I want to do is when the `setIsLoading(() => true);`  runs, the page will be rerendered and shows the loading component while the data is fetching.

But seems the current behavior now is it will wait for the finish of fetching data and then rerender the page. In other words, it doesn't show the loading component immediately right after `setIsLoading(() => true);`  runs.

How can I make the loading component shows immediately right after `setIsLoading(() => true);`  runs while data is fetching, and then rerender the content page after the fetching data done.

Comment: Should it be set to false in the beginning `const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);`

Comment: it is still the same after i set the default to false, the fetching data is still blocking the rerendering

Comment: What is this `getData` function doing and returning? I don't see any overt issues with the code you've shown, it should immediately enqueue a state update to set `isLoading` true, and then some time later after the Promise has resolved, enqueue another update to set it false. My guess here is that `getData` is immediately returning a resolved promise so you don't see the "loading" UI. Need to see all relevant code to confirm. See [mcve].

Comment: FWIW I am unable to reproduce the issue as you describe with your code copy/pasted into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-doesnt-rerender-page-before-fetching-data-50tqvc). Feel free to fork it and add more of your actual code to see if you can make it a reproducible example that we can then inspect and debug live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do.

Here's how I do it:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Theoretically a data we fetch might
    // took like 5-10 seconds to fetch
    const delayFetchStuff = () =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }, 10000);

    // Example of what we're trying to fetch something
    fetch("https://weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com/future.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        // When it done fetching, you can setState the data or anything
        console.log(data);
        // Then from here, you can just use setIsLoading(false)
        delayFetchStuff();
      });

    // Just for clearing timeout, don't need to bother it
    // since I'm theoretically that we fetch a data
    // that took 10 seconds
    return () => clearTimeout(delayFetchStuff);
  }, [isLoading]);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div>Loading spinner or loading component...</div>
      ) : (
        <div>Content go here</div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-visvesvaraya-wnks5u?file=/src/App.js) I created for a fast example

Theoretically, if you fetch data from some specific `URL` or `JSON`, it might take a few seconds to some amount of seconds (maybe around that range), so I create a timeout function for 10 seconds (just for example because in some case, the URL return the data and it's very small at size, which will result that the fetching will be very fast, sometimes you won't even notice that your loading component is rendered or not).

Whenever the data is fetched, the setIsLoading will turn isLoading state to false, from that on, it'll render those fetched data instead of loading spinner or loading component.

Comment: hmmm. seems still a bit different, what i want to achieve is on the same page the id is changed, then loading is set to true to show the loading component. According to the approach you mentioned here, how to set the loading to true and show the loading component immediately instead of being  blocked by fetching data in the next run when something like id changes?

Comment: Do you get the ID from an URL? Like for example: https://exampleurl.com/?id=1

Comment: yes yes exactly, the id will change and reflected on URL

Comment: I know how to do it, but it'll take a few minutes to set up, but just in case, the answer you're looking for is useParams(), which belongs to "react-router-dom" dependencies, install it. Set up a route that uses some params, and binds it to useEffect change dependencies, whenever the params Id is changed, it'll run the useEffect again, then it'll achieve what you want.

Comment: @宏宇魏, maybe this is what you need, I design the Route is /user/1 or user/2, just type it and you will have a list of user IDs, click around and you will achieve what you want. I leave the comment in there as well. StackBlitz React: https://react-uc3ag8.stackblitz.io

Comment: The code is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uc3ag8?file=src/index.js My bad, I post the application URL

Comment: this is what I want to achieve, appreciate for your help very much!

Comment: Why is your suggested solution to *add* 10 seconds to each request's processing time and artificially slow the app down?

Comment: @DrewReese At first, I didn't understand what he wants to achieve, I thought that he didn't see the Loading state of his app because it renders too fast, so I just create a simple solution that set the time out to slow down a bit. But from a few comments above, you can clearly see that his requirements are a bit different from what he's describing, maybe because he's describing it unclear.

Comment: it is just to simulate the slow query for when you have a large amount of data to pull

Comment: yeah Bunny is right, thanks for Bunny's help

Comment: So basically there is no reproducible issue, just a misunderstanding of app/network performance.